# How do I return an index of where a number should go if it isn't found in a Binary Search in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

So I have a binary search code that finds where a number should be placed to maintain sorted order. I've been at this for a little over an hour and a half so far trying to figure this out so I could use a push along.

What value would I return at the end of the method if the value is not found in the array, but the place it should be placed is found? Basically a value that says the index where this number belongs is within +/- 1 of the mid value.

Here is the binary search, i'm not looking to change it but rather just looking for the variable to return where the _____ is.

```
private static int bsearch( int[] arr, int count, int key )
{
    if (count==0) return -1;
    int lo = 0, hi = count - 1, mid;
    while(hi >= lo)
    {
          mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
          if(arr[mid] == key) return mid;
          if ( key < arr[mid] ) hi = mid-1;
          else lo = mid+1;
    }
    return _____;        
}
```

Comment: Think about it like this: if the search value is higher than the last mid you find, itd be mid +1 right? And if its lower shouldnt it be mid -1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most methods return the bitwise negation of the index where to place the element, thus `~idx`.

Binary search makes the assumption that all elements before `lo` are less than the `key` and analogue for `hi`.

In case `hi < lo`, it means that `hi` was set to `mid-1` and `mid` was equal to `lo` (because `hi` and `lo` differ at most one) or analogue to `lo`. Thus the location where the element must be placed is at `lo`. One thus returns:

```
return ~lo;
```

An optimized version of the algorithm is thus:

```
private static int bsearch( int[] arr, int count, int key) {
    if (count==0) return -1;
    int lo = 0, hi = count - 1, mid = hi>>1;
    while(hi >= lo) {
          mid = (lo + hi) >> 1;
          if ( key < arr[mid] ) hi = mid-1;
          else if ( key > arr[mid] ) lo = mid+1;
          else return mid;
    }
    return ~lo;
}
```

As a testcase:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 22; i++) {
    int r = bsearch(new int[] {2,3,7,9,11,15,21},7,i);
    System.out.println(""+i+" -> "+r+" "+(~r));
}
```

gives:

```
0 -> -1 0
1 -> -1 0
2 -> 0 -1
3 -> 1 -2
4 -> -3 2
5 -> -3 2
6 -> -3 2
7 -> 2 -3
8 -> -4 3
9 -> 3 -4
10 -> -5 4
11 -> 4 -5
12 -> -6 5
13 -> -6 5
14 -> -6 5
15 -> 5 -6
16 -> -7 6
17 -> -7 6
18 -> -7 6
19 -> -7 6
20 -> -7 6
21 -> 6 -7
22 -> -8 7
```

`x -> i j` with `i` the result and `j` the bitwise negative (used as insertion index in case `i` is negative).

[**online JDoodle demo**](http://jdoodle.com/a/mQ).

Comment: It results in `-1`. So you can check first if it is less than `0` and if so, again use the bitwise negation to calculate the insertion position is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

See [Arrays.binarySearch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-byte:A-byte-).

```
return -low - 1;
```

A negative number, at most -1. As `mid` (the insertion point) ranges from 0.

> **returns**
>
> index of the search key, if it is contained in the array; otherwise,
>   (-(insertion point) - 1). The insertion point is defined as the point
>   at which the key would be inserted into the array: the index of the
>   first element greater than the key, or a.length if all elements in the
>   array are less than the specified key. Note that this guarantees that
>   the return value will be >= 0 if and only if the key is found.

Comment: With this I get an error that tells me that mid was never initialized, which makes sense because mid is only being initialized within the while loop, how would I deal with this?

Comment: @NoivernEvo: you must initialize `mid` before the `while` loop. For instance with `(lo+hi)>>1`.

Comment: Yes you have to initialize `mid` to 0. Especially for the case of a zero length array. You could also use `lo`.

Comment: @JoopEggen: a testcase with `{2,3,7,9,11,15,21}` gives the wrong result for `22`. One expects `-8` (`-7-1`). But it gives `-7`. Shouldn't one use the `low`?

Comment: Definitely. I generally write the loop differently. Corrected it.

Answer (score -1):

The actually code is `return -1`. But I'm confused your description. What's the "if the value is not found in the array, but the place it should be placed is found?" meaning?
The value is either found in the array or not. It's not found before `while`, which means it's not in the array, so you should `return -1`.

Comment: Binary search normally returns the betwise negation of the index where to place the value.

Comment: The friend who asked the question wrote the wrong code with `mid`, I ignored his code. But in the binary search `return -1` is common sense, ohhhh, what do you want get if the method don't find the value in the array?

Comment: well Java's [binary search](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-byte:A-byte-) doesn't use this common sense, but uses the insert index. It's only if the list is not ordered (as is for instance the case in searching a char in a string), -1 is returned.